# onmicrosoft.com EWS/Exchange.asmx

Tags: ms-office, exchangewebservices

I can't figure out what the url on an onmicrosoft.com or office365.com account for the web services EWS/Exchange.asmx is. All the documentation says it's https:///EWS/Exchange.asmx

I guessed the following but can't get pass the network login password will any of the credentials
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.amsx?rfr=Admin_o365&exsvurl=1&mkt=en-US&Realm=twenty71.onmicrosoft.com&wa=wsignin1.0

I'm really just interested in an economical hosted Exchange service so alternative suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Answered my own question - it's just https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Using your credentials in the network login takes you to a wsdl page